# Check whether array has keys that don't match a list

Tags: php, arrays

What is the easiest way to check if an has array keys that don't match a particular list?

```
$a = array(
  [ignore_me] => "blah blah blah",
  [name] => "Don"
);

does_array_have_non_ignored_entries($a); // returns true
```

I can think of a ton of ways to write this function, didn't know if PHP has a quick solution. Best one I have is this:

```
$length = count($a);
$ignored_entry = (in_array($a, 'ignore_me') ? 1 : 0;
if ($length - $ignored_entry > 0) {...}
```

Comment: funny to see all these different solutions for such a relatively easy problem :)

Comment: @NDM Just like there are many solutions to FizzBuzz ;) I actually failed an online PHP test because my solutions were too unconventional for the system to understand XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this, using standard functions, is as follows:

```
$ignored_keys = array("ignore_me"); // can be extended to ignore several keys
$diff = array_diff_key($array,array_flip($ignored_keys));
if( $diff) {
    // there are keys that weren't ignored.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$count = isset($a['ignore_me']) ? count($a) -1 : count($a);
```

Substract 1, if that key is found, else use the full length.

Comment: DRY: `$count = count($a)-isset($a['ignore_me']);`

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is the [`array_diff_key` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff-key.php)

```
$count = count(array_diff_key(array('ignore_me'=>null), $a)));
```

Comment: But sadly this is kinda a rehash of kolink's answer .

Comment: Just less readable, and with the added hassle of defining values for each key to ignore :p

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($a as $key => $row)
{
    if($key == 'ignore_me')
    {
        unset($array[$key]);
    }
}
$count = count($array);
```

Comment: Alters the array, can't use it :/

Comment: Bad idea, this method is destructive (modifies the original array)

Answer (score 0):

for this you can use a array in built function as:

```
$a = array(
  [ignore_me] => "blah blah blah",
  [name] => "Don"
);


if (array_key_exists("ignore_me",$a))
   {
   echo "Key exists!";
   }
else
   {
   echo "Key does not exist!";
   }
?>
```